# back4app data model relationship filtering

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, parse-platform, back4app

I use back4app as my backend environment which is almost similar to Parse.

I would like to ask a few questions regarding organising data models relationships. Let me add a few words about my structure:

I have a `User` data model and a `Project` data model. Project can contain many `User` records. When I want to put a user to a project I wrap it to another data model called `ProjectUser`. I need this for separating levels when a `User` can be a part of entire system and when a `User` can be just a part of smaller things such as `Project` component I've described.

`ProjectUser` class has a `User` and `Project` as **Relation** (not sure do I need to use Pointer here):

[image]

So now looks like I can filter `ProjectUser` using `Project` key and get all needed users in appropriate project.

My question do I need to use such approach with filtering or do I need to add a new column to `Project` class with **Array** type and append this array every time I put new `ProjectUser` to a destination project? Can my `Project` class just contain array of another custom classes?

To summarise:

1. Do I need to use pointers instead of relations?
2. Is this better to create additional object with two custom classes in it (`ProjectUser`) or it's ok to use an array in Project data model to retrieve all `Users` or `ProjectUsers`.

Comment: Relation is for many-to-many relationship. Since you already have a joint class (ProjectUser), you should use pointers in this joint class to User and Project. Another approach would be the use of a Relation called users from the Project class to the User class (without using the joint class). You can see more details about the options you have here: http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#relations

Comment: thanks for valuable comments it helped a lot!

Comment: @DaviMacêdo you can post it as answers I will accept it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

UP
Faced the same question

have back4app as backend ad table to filter by related object (User).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).